# How to write a mathematical formula in Java

Tags: java, math, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to figure out a way of converting kilograms (entered by user) to stone and pounds.

For example:

User enters weight as 83.456 kgs, multiply this by 2.204622 to convert to pounds = 184 lbs, divide 184 lbs by 14 to convert to stone = 13.142 stone.

Use the first two digits (13) for stone and separate the remainder to multiply by 14 to get pounds, 0.142 (this is remainder) x 14 = 1.988 lbs, or is there another way to get this result?

Therefore the persons weight is 13 stone and 2 pounds (rounded up or down).

Here's what I have (that works) so far:

```
pounds = kgs*2.204622;  
System.out.printf("Your weight in pounds is: %.0f" , pounds);
System.out.print(" Ibs\n");
stone = pounds / 14
//Can't figure out how to finish the formula in code
```

Comment: Use `long pounds = Math.round(kgs*2.204622)`, then use `/` division and `%` remainder operators to calculate stones and remaining pounds.

Comment: Or if, for whatever reason, you don't care to use `%`:  `long stone = pounds / 14; int lbRem = pounds -  (stone * 14);`

Comment: @Andreas Hmm, I would think that one wants `floor` (i.e. round down) instead of `round` (which can round up or down). What's left over after rounding down is the fractional part of the larger unit (stones in this case).

Comment: @RobertDodier Question specifically says: *Therefore the persons weight is 13 stone and 2 pounds (**rounded up or down**).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution rounds early. Here is code as suggested by [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567582/how-to-write-a-mathematical-formula-in-java?noredirect=1#comment103453199_58567582):

```
double kgs = 83.456;
long pounds = Math.round(kgs*2.204622);
System.out.println("Your weight is " + pounds / 14 + " stone and " + pounds % 14 + " pounds");
```

*Output*

```
Your weight is 13 stone and 2 pounds
```

If you instead use **69.853 kgs**, you get

```
Your weight is 11 stone and 0 pounds
```

but this is where thing get dicey if you don't round early.

---

Both solutions in the (currently accepted) [answer by Lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58567698/5221149) are wrong, since they round at the wrong time. There is a reason you have to round early.

If you change to use 69.853 kgs in those two solutions, you get

```
Solution 1:
  Stone: 10
  Pounds: 14

Solution 2:
  Stone: 10
  Pounds: 14.0
```

Both are obviously incorrect, since `Pounds` should not be 14, aka 1 stone.

The reason for the rounding errors becomes evident if you print the values without rounding

```
double kgs = 69.853;
double pounds = kgs*2.204622;
System.out.println(pounds + " lbs = " + pounds / 14 + " stone and " + pounds % 14 + " pounds");
```

*Output*

```
153.99946056599998 lbs = 10.999961468999999 stone and 13.999460565999982 pounds
```

Comment: Great explanation. I now fully understand all answers and why yours is the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you declared `pounds` and `stone` before using them here (i.e. with `float pounds;` or `double pounds;` or `float pounds =` something), or the code wouldn't compile otherwise.

One way to do this is to do it in 2 separate steps, as below:

```
double kg = 83.456;
double pounds = kg * 2.204622;

double stonesWithDecimal = pounds / 14;

int stone = (int) stonesWithDecimal; // Strip off the decimal
long poundsWithoutStone = Math.round((stonesWithDecimal - stone) * 14); // Take the fractional remainder and multiply by 14
System.out.println("Stone: " + stone + "\nPounds: " + poundsWithoutStone);
```

Andreas's suggestion is definitely much cleaner, though I wanted to present both since I'm not sure what your familiarity level is with using modulo in programming.
Here's one implementation of that suggestion, though you can do this a few different ways in terms of dealing with the data types (Math.round wants to return a `long`):

```
double kg = 83.456;
double pounds = kg * 2.204622;

int stone = (int) pounds / 14;
pounds = (double) Math.round(pounds %= 14);

System.out.println("Stone: " + stone + "\nPounds: " + pounds);
```

Comment: You're right, I had declared the variables as `double` earlier in the class so had a bit of trouble with the other suggestions. Your second suggestion is the solution, it works great. I spent a lot of time trying to figure it out, I would not have solved it by myself, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an extensible ready to use library, you can consider Free & open-sourced library **[UnitOf](https://digidemic.github.io/UnitOf/)**

It offers 30+ conversion out of the box for **Mass**.

**Example** :

```
double kgFromPound = new UnitOf.Mass().fromPounds(5).toKilograms(); 

double poundFromKg = new UnitOf.Mass().fromKilograms(5).toPounds();
```

Hope it helps!